# How to catch a certain part of a website?

Tags: javascript

Suppose that we have a website. We want to show a specified part of this site in another site, like a table of data that shows latest news, and we want to show this part in our website with javascript.

Is this possible? Are there any more information needed?

We all know that with this code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.XYZ.com">
</iframe>
```

we can load all website, but how to load a specific part of a website?

Comment: If you don't own both sites, this is frowned on. If a site wants you doing stuff like this they'll supply an API, widget, RSS feed, etc. And if you do own both sites, you could be sharing this content on the back end, not scraping via Javascript on the front.

Comment: Google  screen scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think your best bet is [`JQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but I'm not up to speed on whether there are crossdomain problems with that approach.</strike> • *Just checked and there are.*

You can use PHP to load the output of a page with [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) or similar and then scrape out what you want for your own output.

Example:

```
$str = file_get_contents("http://ninemsn.com.au/");

// Reallly shouldn't use regex with HTML.
$region = '/(\<div id\=\"tabloid\_2\" class\=\"tabloids\">)(.*)(\<\/div\>)/';
preg_match($region, $str, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

Finally, something to keep in the back of your mind is that many of the larger websites that developers may want to get content from for their own website offer APIs to easily and efficiently obtain information from their site. YouTube, Twitter and a number of photo sharing sites are good examples of these. JSON and XML are probably the most common data formats that you will receive from these APIs.

Here are some examples of APIs that produce usable JSON:

- YouTube video feed: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Martyaced/uploads?alt=json
- Twitter feed: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Martyaced

Comment: I wrote it when there was just one paragraph:D.for that two php codes.

Comment: @foreign.man Okay, give the PHP I updated my answer with a try to see what I mean. It's an extremely fiddly approach - site owners don't really want you to scrape content from their site; if they want you to be able to do that, they'll provide an API to do so.

Comment: thanks, is that work for a table (td)? and how can i use it in my website? (i'm new with php)

Comment: @foreign.man You need to be using a server that supports PHP and the file needs to be a `.php` file. The code above also needs to be wrapped in `<?php ...code... ?>`.